# Получения координат рамки

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2

url = 'yaroslav.jpg'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
ret, img = cap.read()

cv2.imshow('img', img)

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imwrite(r'res.png', img)
```

Есть алгоритм, который взял из интернета, надо получить координаты рамки, которой обозначается лицо. Для дальнейшего вырезания лица.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмите координаты рамки из вызова функции [cv2.rectangle()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga07d2f74cadcf8e305e810ce8eed13bc9):

```
(x,y),(x+w,y+h)
```

- `(x,y)` - левый верхний угол прямоугольника
- `(x+w,y+h)` - правый нижний угол прямоугольника

Comment: Поможете? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/898561/Ошибка-в-openСv-Как-исправить