# Ошибка в OpenСV Как исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Professional/PycharmProjects/tests/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:356: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:856)
warning: yaroslav.jpg (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:857)
```

Вот код

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image

url = 'yaroslav.jpg'

# читаем фото из интернета
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
ret, img = cap.read()

cv2.imshow('img', img)

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imwrite(r'res.png', img)

print(x, y, x+w, y+h)

img2 = Image.open('yaroslav1.jpg')

img3 = img2.crop(x, y, x+w, y+h)

img3.save('res.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите правильный/полный путь к `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`:

```
import sys
import cv2
from pathlib import Path

def save_all_faces(img, file_pattern='d:/temp/res_{:03}.jpg'):
    faces_model_path = Path(sys.executable).parent / Path('Library/etc/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(str(faces_model_path))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for i, (x, y, w, h) in enumerate(faces, start=1):
        cv2.imwrite(file_pattern.format(i), img[y:y+h, x:x+w])
        #img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        #roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        #roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/x92It.jpg'

# читаем фото из интернета
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
ret, img = cap.read()

save_all_faces(img, file_pattern='d:/temp/res_{:03}.jpg')
```

результат [`D:\temp\res_001.jpg`]:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дело в том, что до этого работало. До добавления Обреза картинки с помощью PIL. И да, ваш способ тоже не помог

Comment: @МаксимХалин, зачем вам вообще использовать `PIL` если вы уже используете `OpenCV` - у него гораздо богаче функционал